# How to skip first element in array with foreach?

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

Say I have an array:

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Now I can iterate it via foreach:

```
foreach ( @arr ) {
    print $_;
}
```

But is there a way to iterate from second (for example) to last elemnt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is perl. There are more than one way to do it, always. Such as an array slice:

```
for (@arr[1 .. $#arr])   # for and foreach are exactly the same in perl
```

You can use `shift` as Andy Lester suggested, however this will of course alter your original array.

Comment: And of course, there's `for (1..$#arr) { ... $arr[$_] ... }` (which uses O(1) memory instead of O(N))

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do it. I opted for one of them, though I could have shown all of them.

Comment: Not exactly the same. `for` provides the current array index in `$_`. `foreach` provides the current element.

Comment: @Demnogonis: That is *not true*. `for` and `foreach` are *identical* in Perl

Comment: @Borodin: Dang, you're right. I thought it worked that way... Sorry for telling guff.

Comment: @Demnogonis `The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you can use either.` Quote from [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops).

Answer (score 10):

Just shift off the first element before you go looping.

```
my @arr = ( 1..5 );
shift @arr; # Remove the first element and throw it away

foreach ( @arr ) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```